# "A physics prof bet me $10,000 I'm wrong", is this correct?

Tags: idiomatic-language

There is a video titled "A Physics Prof Bet Me $10,000 I'm Wrong".
Does this sound natural? It feels that there is something missing between "$10,000" and "I'm wrong" but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sometimes optional subordinator "that" has been omitted.

> A physics prof bet me $10,000 **that** I'm wrong.